# Error running batch file - Unexpected Switch at this level

Tags: batch-file

I have the following batch code which runs fine, outputs fine and even saves fine but each time I run I get an error saying

> Unexpected Switch at this level

Can you please help me understand why I am getting this, although the command runs as desired, it is just irksome.

```
@echo off
if exist C:\dell\%computername%.csv del C:\dell\%computername%.csv
set outputfile="C:\dell\%computername%.csv"
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic os get csname /value') do SET CSNAME=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic os get caption /value') do SET CAPTION=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic computersystem get manufacturer /value') do SET MANUFACTURER=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic computersystem get model /value') do SET MODEL=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic os get osarchitecture /value') do SET OSBIT=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic cpu get name /value') do SET PROC=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic bios get softwareelementid /value') do SET BIOSVER=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic computersystem get totalphysicalmemory /value') do SET MEM=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic ntdomain get dnsforestname /value') do SET DOMAIN=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic bios get serialnumber /value') do SET SERVICETAG=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic computersystem get username /value') do SET USERNAME=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('WMIC path Win32_VideoController get Name /value') do SET GRAPHICCARD=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic sounddev get productname /value') do SET AUDIODEVICE=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get status /value') do SET BATTERYSTATUS=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic cdrom get caption /value') do SET CDROM=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic path win32_pointingdevice get hardwaretype /value') do SET MOUSE=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic path win32_keyboard get description /value') do SET KEYBOARD=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic path win32_desktopmonitor /value') do SET MONITOR=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic computersystem get numberoflogicalprocessors /value') do SET PROCESSORNUM=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic path win32_logicaldisk where "drivetype = 3" get size /value') do SET HDDSIZE=%%i
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic nicconfig get dhcpserver /value') do SET DHCP=%%i

echo Compname,OsName,Manufacturer,Model,OsBit,Proc,BiosVersion,Memory,Domain,ServiceTag,UserName,GraphicCard,AudioDevice,BatteryStatus,CDROM,Mouse, Keyboard,Monitor,NumOfProc,HDDSize,DHCP>>%outputfile%
echo %CSNAME%,%CAPTION%,%MANUFACTURER%,%MODEL%,%OSBIT%,%PROC%,%BIOSVER%,%MEM%,%DOMAIN%,%SERVICETAG%,%USERNAME%,%GRAPHICCARD%,%AUDIODEVICE%,%BATTERYSTATUS%,%CDROM%,%MOUSE%,%KEYBOARD%,%MONITOR%,%PROCESSORNUM%,%HDDSIZE%,%DHCP%>>%outputfile%
```

Comment: It's `wmic path win32_desktopmonitor /value`; it doesn't seem to like `/value`.

Comment: Please learn [how to debug batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)...

Comment: Agreed aschipfl.. And thanks.. It indeed was a silly mistake.. Sorry guys!!

Comment: Just a note, it is common for multiple NICs and even monitors, you may be able to improve detection in these cases with lines such as `wmic nicconfig where "ipenabled = true" get…` and `wmic path win32_desktopmonitor where "availability = 3" get…`

Comment: Thanks Compo, the suggestion for desktop monitor helped but in case of DHCP, say if I am connected to LAN and WAN, I will have 2 DHCPs right? Then my output will fail. How will I overcome that? Lemme know if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CristiFati [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384786/error-running-batch-file-unexpected-switch-at-this-level#comment66098417_39384786), the command that raises the error is

```
wmic path win32_desktopmonitor /value
```

The reason is indicated in the [`wmic` command line reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx) : `/VALUE` is not a switch for `wmic`, but for the `GET` verb. As you are not using any verb in this command, you can not include the switch.

Comment: Yikes!!! it was a boo boo.. Feel free to condemn me on this.. :(

But thanks a bunch.. Yes, I see what an idiot I am..